# Yii2 performance: render view takes too long

Tags: gridview, yii2

While rendering the view in Yii2, I noticed the render time is a bit too long.
And here is a part of log:

> 03:57:57.435  info    yii\db\Command::query   SELECT * FROM `user_profile`
> WHERE `userid` IN (16, 15, 12)
>
> 03:57:57.501  trace   yii\base\View::renderFile

please notice the time between in the two steps, almost takes more than 80ms.
The render view is simple, just a gridview widget with my own code. The less page size is, the less render time it costs. When the column is about 15 items it almost takes **250ms** to render the view. Besides, the sql queries takes 2ms in total.

```
'columns' => [
            [
                'header' => 'Article title',
                'attribute' => 'article_title',
                'format' => 'html',
                'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
                    /**
                     * bunch of code
                    */
                    return $info;
                },
            ],
        ],
```

So is that the code file causes this? Should I rebuild my code?

Comment: what does the network panel shows if it is not related to your db? are you using any `AppAssets` bundle for you application.

Comment: Just the default appasset, and the network shows the page Waiting (TTFB) 261.22 ms

Comment: I experience the same behaviour. As soon as gridview gets involved, renderFile will introduce wait times of up to 1000 ms (in my case) on a beefy server.

Comment: @SebiF I currently reduce the pagesize as the temporary solution, I guess I have to rewrite a gridview which suits my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this problem, TTFBs of 250ms to 1sec. By modifying Apache to use fpm setup, you should be able to reduce  load times down to 35ms.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/php-fpm-on-cloud/amp/

Comment: Thank you for your info, I will check it later.

Comment: You should be able to reduce your time down to about 35ms, a little longer if heavy queries are involved.

Comment: Now i'm using fpm, it's true the render times reduce much!